# XCode error when running Flutter app io.flutter.1.ui (7): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

When I run a Flutter app in XCode to test on my device, it crashes with the following error:

io.flutter.1.ui (7): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

And with the console output:

2020-04-27 04:19:43.163796+0200 Runner[7015:465670] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-04-27 04:19:43.350671+0200 Runner[7015:465854] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:56076/-SAyMQRWKAg=/

I have run this app at least a 100 times and everything worked fine, updated to new XCode, started it once, it worked and then tried again and everything fell apart. First I lost all my header files so I had to remake the whole app and now I am getting this error. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If anyone has the same error, I finally managed to solve it by doing the following:

1.) Switch to Flutter master channel using:
   'code' flutter channel master 'code'

2.) Clean flutter:
  'code' flutter clean 'code'

This will take a lot of time but it worked for me. If you try to build the app now, you'll still get the same console output but it won't crash and it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has the same error, I finally managed to solve it by doing the following:

1.) Switch to Flutter master channel using:

```
    flutter channel master
```

2.) Clean flutter:

```
    flutter clean
```

This will take a lot of time but it worked for me. If you try to build the app now, you'll still get the same console output but it won't crash and it will work fine